# Calling System.Timers.Timer.Stop from the timer thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

In the following C# code, System.Timers.Timer.Stop is called from the timer thread but also from the UI thread:

```
private void StartTimer()
{
    // This is in the context of the UI thread.
    this.m_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    this.m_timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // This is in the context of the timer thread.

        try
        {
            this.m_timer.Stop();

            // Do some stuff.

            this.m_timer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            CTrace.Exception(this, "StartTimer", exception);
        }
    };
    this.m_timer.Start();
}
// After returning from the StartTimer() method, this.m_timer.Stop() 
// will be called from the UI thread.
```

Is calling `System.Timers.Timer.Start` and `System.Timers.Timer.Stop` from the timer thread safe? Is it thread safe?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this.m_timer.Stop() can be called from the thread of the Elapsed call back, that's fine.  One thing to be careful of is if "// Do some stuff" code interacts with the UI, then you have to Invoke/BeginInvoke onto the UI thread.

Comment: It is thread-safe, nothing will blow up and billow smoke.  Actually ensuring the Elapsed event won't run anymore is not generally possible, it could have been scheduled to run on a threadpool thread a microsecond before you called Stop().  And of course yours will enable the timer again so it won't work.  Use System.Threading.Timer instead, its Dispose(WaitHandle) overload provides an interlock guarantee.

Comment: @HansPassant I want to disagree, calling `Stop()` twice would be the same as setting `Enabled = false` twice. shouldn't it be possible for [this line](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs,119) to throw a null refrence exception if two threads are in the `if(timer != null)` block at the same time but 1+ lines appart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `Stop()` nor `Start()` method is not listed as thread safe in the MSDN in it's documentation.

To be the most safe you should lock on all operations that are not listed as thread safe in the MSDN when working with multiple threads.

However there are other issues with your code, you replace `this.m_timer` when you start a new timer, however in the timer callback code you also use `this.m_timer`, this means if you start a timer then start a 2nd one both of the callbacks will be using the same `m_timer`. You should instead just use a single timer and not create it inside the start function.

Also instead of manually stopping the timer set `AutoReset` to `false`, this gives you the behavior you are trying to do automatically.

```
private object m_timerLock;
private bool m_timerRunning = false;

public YourClass()
{
    this.m_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    this.m_timer.AutoReset = false;
    this.m_timer.Elapsed += TimerCallback;
}

private void StartTimer()
{
    // This is in the context of the UI thread.
    lock(this.m_timerLock)
    {
        this.m_timerRunning = true;
        this.m_timer.Start();
    }
}

private void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is in the context of the timer thread.

    try
    {
        //This line is not needed anymore because of the this.m_timer.AutoReset = false.
        //this.m_timer.Stop();

        // Do some stuff.

        lock(this.m_timerLock)
        {
            //This checks to see if StopTimer() was called while the callback was running.
            if(this.m_timerRunning)
                this.m_timer.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        CTrace.Exception(this, "StartTimer", exception);
    }
}

public void StopTimer()
{
    lock(this.m_timerLock)
    {
        this.m_timer.Stop();
        this.m_timerRunning = false;
    }
}
```